# Force reloading of a facebook page tab after user click LIKE inside iframe. Possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Can i force a facebook page tab to reload after user click LIKE inside iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reload the page after <fb:like> is clicked?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4978778/is-there-a-way-to-reload-the-page-after-fblike-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Subscribe to the [`edge.create` FB.Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to detect the like event and when you detect the event, do `top.location.href=top.location.href;`

Comment: This doesnt work: 

  Permission denied to access property 'href'  
  top.location.href = top.location.href;

Comment: @Mikepote Try explicitly declaring the URL, then. i.e. `top.location.href='https://facebook.com/page/app_12345';`

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! That comment worked for me declaring the url explicitly!

Comment: Is this still valid? I just need to know as I am preparing some documentation. Thanks. EDIT: They automatically refresh the iframe now, I suppose?.

Comment: Declaring the URL still works, however every usage to `top` has been effectively banned...

Comment: @Aznim What? You can't access the `top` window's contents because of cross-domain restrictions, but `top.location.href` can still be modified as always.