# canvas app - reload canvas app after login - origin restriction

Tags: facebook, iframe, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

Not exactly a fbook specific question but:

I have simple code which logs user via FB JS SDK, in the CB i'm trying to reload the top frame in order to preserve request data.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   top.location.reload()
})
```

This code is being blocked by chrome because the top object cannot be accessed from my own domain code,

I'm getting:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost/xxxx" from accessing a frame with origin 
"http://apps.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to
"facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain"
to the same value to allow access.
```

So, how exactly can I reload the browser URL again after performing the login?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force reloading of a facebook page tab after user click LIKE inside iframe. Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347916/force-reloading-of-a-facebook-page-tab-after-user-click-like-inside-iframe-poss)